# Running a single Matlab parpool job across multiple nodes of a cluster using the Slurm scheduler

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, slurm

I am running a Matlab script called EmitCue on a remote cluster using the Slurm scheduler. To submit a job that will run in parallel across 24 CPU cores on a single node, I use a shell script such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -A AccountName
#SBATCH -J JobName
#SBATCH -N 1           # The number of nodes
#SBATCH -c 24          # The number of cpu cores to use

module purge
module load rhel7/default-peta4 matlab

echo "SLURM_JOBID="$SLURM_JOBID

# This sets up a separate Matlab preferences directory for each parpool job to prevent interference
export MATLAB_PREFDIR=/home/jbh40/matlab_prefs/$SLURM_JOBID/prefs

# Command to execute Matlab code
matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "EmitCue(${1},${2},'${3}')" # > matoutfile
```

Inside EmitCue (in Matlab), I call parpool('local',24). This works fine.

Now, I would like to speed up the job by using 32 CPU cores. However, each node has only 24 CPU cores. Hence, I would like the job to be distributed across 2 nodes (e.g., 16 CPU cores on 2 nodes; or 24 cores one one node and 8 on another node). I'm not sure how to do this. I tried setting #SBATCH -N 2 and #SBATCH -c 16, but when I called parpool('local',32) in EmitCue, I got the following error message:

> Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ...   Error
>   using parpool (line 113)   You requested a minimum of 32 workers, but
>   the cluster "local" has the NumWorkers property set to allow a maximum
>   of 16 workers. To run a communicating job on more workers than this
>   (up to a maximum of 512 for the Local cluster), increase the value of
>   the NumWorkers property for the cluster. The default value of
>   NumWorkers for a Local cluster is the number of cores on the local
>   machine.

Can anybody suggest how I can achieve this.

Comment: Probably, the 'local' cluster is just a single machine so, with that profile, if the maximum number of cores is 24, this is all you can get. Alternatively, you could create your own profile: check the documentation (https://es.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/discover-clusters-and-use-cluster-profiles.html#f5-16540).

Comment: Hey @Poshi. I created a cluster profile for slurm in the Matlab GUI. In the cluster profile, I set Numworkers to 128 and NumThreads to 1, but I leave all other features at their default values. My goal is to now run a job on 2 nodes of a remote cluster, where each node of the cluster has 64 physical cores but presents 256 cpus via hyper-threading. I specify #SBATCH -N 2 in the job script. In EmitCue.m I call: parpool(MyProfile,128), but the job hangs indefinitely at the following line: Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'knlw128t1_Import' profile. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but I never used `matlab`. I cannot give you sxact details. Tell `SLURM` to us two nodes, but also 128 tasks of 1 CPU per task each. Just to make sure it is what `SLURM` is getting. Also try to initialize your parpool at lower number of processors to make sure the issue is related to extending to multiple nodes, not a single node issue.